# how to check the file on remote host is exsit with shell script

Tags: shell, expect

i want check some files on remote host are exsit with shell script,for my local machine and remote host are not be trusted with each other,so i use expect in my script,here are my code

```
expect << EOF

spawn ssh $src_user@$src_host "test -f $src_pub || echo CheckFalse "

expect {
        "yes/no*" {
                send "yes\n"
            }
        "$src_host's password:" {
            send "$src_passwd\n"
            }   

         eof { exit }
        }

expect CheckFalse { exit 11 }

EOF

if [ $? -ne 11 ];then
    echo "file is  exsit!"      
else
    echo "file is not exsit!"
fi
```

Comment: So what part do you have issue? what's the error message?

Comment: i use sh -x to track the result,and found $? == 0,so it's not correct

Answer (score 0):

Use `ssh` with a command (using -c).

```
ssh otherhost -c 'ls /path/ filename'
```

And parse the output as you wish

Comment: Note that key-based authentication will be needed with this approach, which OP does not show as in place above (he is using password). I highly recommend switching from password-based auth to key-based auth, though.

Comment: i got an error "Unknown cipher type" when using -c command,and also,i'm using bash,not ksh.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few issues with your script

- Using test will only check if the file doesn't exist, rather use ls which gives output in both conditions and is easier to work with in this case.
- You should use exp_continue after sending the authenticity check and the password so the expect loop can continue from where it left of from the previous match.
- Add checks for $src_pub and 'No such file' in your expect block to trap for both conditions as shown below:

Try below:

```
spawn ssh $src_user@$src_host "ls $src_pub"

expect {
    "yes/no*" {
        send "yes\n"
        exp_continue
    }

    -re "(.*)assword:" {
        send -- "$src_passwd\n"   
    }

    $src_pub {
        exit 0;
    }

    -re "(.*) No such" {
        exit 1;
    }
}
```